# MeteorJS Mup deployment: Hanging on 'node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download '

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, fabricjs, node-pre-gyp

My MeteorJS mup deployment to digital ocean has suddenly stopped working today.

On attempting to deploy to the server via MUP it successfully pushes the bundle to the server, but --verbose shows it is just hangs on the below and doesn't successfully 'Prepare Bundle'. There is no error at all - no matter how long I leave it. The app is running fine on my localhost.

I am on Meteor 1.10.2, Node 12.16.1 and NPM 6.14.

The point at which hangs at MUPs 'Prepare bundle' is below:

```
> canvas@2.6.1 install /built_app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/canvas
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
```

Canvas is a dependency of FabricJS, both NPM modules. I have successfully deployed to the server yesterday with FabricJS

Comment: Have you tried to reset `meteor reset` and delete node modules via `rm -rf ./node_modules` and reinstall everything?

Comment: What about your other mup question? Is this solved? Please close deprecated questions or answer them yourself if you found a solution.

Comment: Hi Jankapunkt - I woke up the next day, made no different changes, and it no longer hung on the above line. I have successfully deployed multiple times over thge last few days, however, as I am typing this, I have the exact same issue again. This leads to me believe that this is an issue on the request side for node-pre-gyp, but I still dontunderstand how to fix it (or if it can be fixed).

Comment: Can you share your mup.js file with us?